# React-hook-form and MUI TextField testing with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form with zod for schema validation and MUI for UI components.
I have this MUI TextField wrapped in Controll HOC from RHF:

```
                    <Controller
                        name="docRegistrationNumber"
                        control={control}
                        defaultValue=""
                        render={({
                            field: { ref, onChange, value, ...field },
                        }) => (
                            <TextField
                                label="docRegistrationNumber"
                                variant="outlined"
                                error={Boolean(errors.docRegistrationNumber)}
                                helperText={
                                    errors.docRegistrationNumber?.message
                                }
                                inputRef={ref}
                                onChange={(event) => {
                                    if (errors.docRegistrationNumber) {
                                        trigger('docRegistrationNumber')
                                    }
                                    onChange(event.target.value)
                                }}
                                {...field}
                                value={value}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
```

I'm trying to test the input for error messages.
A use case would be: if the input text is longer than 10 characters, display a error message below the input field "Invalid input".

What I'm trying in my test file is the following:

```
test('Should display error message for text longer than 10 characters', async () => {
            const input = screen.getByRole('textbox', {
                name: /docRegistrationNumber/i,
            })
            await user.type(input, 'this text is longer than 10 characters')
            await user.tab()
            const errorMessage = await screen.findByText(/invalid input/i)
            expect(errorMessage).toBeInTheDocument()
        })
```

This does not seems to work. It cannot find element with that error text.
I tried using fireEvent to blur the input, but got same results.
I tried wrapping the expect in a `waitFor` block with no results.

This is my test setup:

```
const Component = () => {
        const {
            control,
            formState: { errors },
        } = useForm()
        return (
            <ContactAttributes
                errors={errors}
                control={control as any}
                trigger={jest.fn()}
                contactDetails={EMPTY_DETAILS_OBJECT}
            />
        )
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        render(<Component />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter })
    })
```

My guess is that the errors are not generated at test runtime. If I pass the error explicitly in the `errors` props I can query that error message.

My question is, how should I test this input?
In react-hook-form documentation I saw they test the whole form and check for errors only when submitting the form button.

Thank you!

Using `userEvent` instead of `fireEvent`
Wrapping the expectation in `waitFor`

My expectation was to be able to query the error message.